# How to get the selected result in next webpage in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to select some cities and show the selected results in the next page. I am able to this get the result in the same page but I can't take the desired result in to the next webpage. Suppose users select NYC and Delhi, this selected cities (NYC and Delhi) will be shown in another html page.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var markedCheckbox = document.getElementsByName('pl');
  for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked)
      document.body.append(checkbox.value + ' ');
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 style="color:green"> Get all marked checkboxes value </h2>
<h4> Select the City, you know </h4>
<tr>
  <td> Berlin: <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="pl" value="Berlin"> </td>
  <td> NYC: <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="pl" value="NYC"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Delhi: <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="pl" value="Delhi"> </td>
  <td> London: <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="pl" value="London"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Paris: <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="pl" value="Paris"> </td>
  <td> Dhaka: <input type="checkbox" id="check6" name="pl" value="Dhaka"> </td> <br> <br>


  <button id="btn">Submit</button> <br>
  <h4 style="color:green" id="result"></h4>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="12.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have PHP available on the server?

Comment: Also - is that your actual HTML? If yes there are errors ( The head comes before the body ), you don't open or close the HTML table element

Comment: "*but I can't take the desired result in to the next webpage*'; Please [edit] your question to add some more details. How are you 'moving to the next page'. There are multiple options to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to showing your data on another page, you must have save your data somewhere. You can use PHP session or localStorage feature of JavaScript. If you want to use localStorage, you can modify you JavaScript code.

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
  var markedCheckbox = document.getElementsByName("pl");
  var cities = [];

  for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      cities.push(checkbox.value);
    }
  }

  // Saving data into storage
  localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(cities));

  // get data from storage on other pages
  var showCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cities"));

  showCities.forEach((city) => {
    document.body.append(city + " ");
  });
};
```

Since your data is saved into `localStorage` now, you can get your data from `localStorage` in any HTML page.

If you want to access localStorage data in other HTML pages,

```
var showCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cities"));

showCities.forEach((city) => {
  document.body.append(city + " ");
});
```

Just put this code into the script tag of that HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir. sir, how can I write the code for html to read this js code. I am trying but not able to read it by html.

Comment: I have added the way to read the checkbox data from another html pages, in my answer. Please feel free to accept and upvote my answer, if it solved your problem.